# How to debug sqlite's execute method that never ends?

Tags: python, sqlite, debugging

I've got a rather strange issue with pandas' `read_sql_query` on my staging server. It never ends. The exact same code and libraries runs on my dev machine under 3 seconds and the query itself executes under half a second. It reads an SQLite database. When I copy that database to my dev machine, again, no issues. I even copied my dev setup to the staging server and it simply doesn't ever end. When I start the Task Manager the python.exe process hangs there with 50% CPU usage (the VM has 2 CPUs) for an hour or two or more.

What can I do to crack it?

---

I tried the same query with only sqlite and it hangs too so apparently it's not an issue with pandas.

Comment: It was an issue with sqlite 3.39.4. I've updated python to 3.10.11 that brought sqlite 3.40.1 and now it works! :-\ Unbelievable!

Comment: One (common) reason for this behavior would be a table that is locked by some other process. Sqlite is not my area of expertise - I would be interested in what kind of timeout behavior is in play here, and also how you would be able to verify locks in a working sqlite database. The upgrade "fixing the problem" could be coincidence - especially if it involved some kind of closing of all connections to the database for the upgrade.